# upgrading windows 8 single language to windows 8 pro with volume license key

Tags: windows-8, license

How can I upgrade Windows 8 OEM single-language to Windows 8 Pro with a Volume License Key?
I use the **Add Features to Windows 8** -> Enter the volume licensing product key and it does not accept it. It shows "This Key Won't work"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't upgrade to a VLK. You need to have it installed from the DVD made from your VLK provider